# Self standing objects

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I was trying to create a simple glass and use physics on it. Well my problem is, that it can not fall on side and it is still going back standing on bottom.

Does anybody know how to solve this? it looks like it has bottom heavy as block of concrete.

Comment: Hi, please add screenshots and/or a .blend file (http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) to *clearly* show the issue you are having. Currently, it is very unclear what you have tried and what methods you are using.

Comment: Reset the origin with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`C` *> Origin to Center of Mass* and see if that helps any.

Comment: @RayMairlot We do have [new .blend service](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)(non-expireing :D )

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Was just waiting for some feedback on your meta post before suggesting it to users.

Comment: Okay... quite alot of feedback givin in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) just not on meta. Its pretty robust now after @stacker gave it a rundown

Comment: Thank you NovieInDisguise, the origin made the difference I wanted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is change the origin by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *> Origin to Center of Mass*.

What is happening is the physical representation of the mesh is confused by the non-symmetrical mesh, it instead calculates it as if half of the mesh is below the origin, making it very bottom heavy.

[image: RigidBodyGif]

Comment: Did it and it works :) thank you once again :)

Comment: @Deny You can accept this answer then by clicking the checkmark below the voting buttons. It shows that a satisfactory answer has been posted, and helps site stats